# Reading sms inbox programmatically Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, mobile, sms, firefox-os

I searched [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Apps/Reference) for sms api, but could not find anything. Is it even possible to send/read sms messages on Firefox OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of its high-impact security implications, the WebSMS API currently is only available for **certified** applications on Firefox OS (see [WebSMS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/WebSMS)).

Certified applications are the ones included in the operating system itself, so - as a third party developer - at the moment you can not create applications that can use this Web API. Accessing the SMS API is a much requested feature, though, so there is work going on to make this possible in the OS on the long term, but not in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Api docs is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.mozSetMessageHandler):

```
navigator.mozSetMessageHandler('sms-received', function(sms){

});
```

**EDIT**: [Sending, deleting, mark as read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SmsManager)...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send sms on firefox OS, but as there is high-impact security implications before using sms api in manifest.webapp file you have to edit type field as "type": "certified" and
in the permission field you have to add "sms":{}.

After that to send sms you can use following code

```
var message = "hi"; //sms content
var number = "0191147689"; //mobile no you want to send sms
var request;
try{

    request = navigator.mozMobileMessage.send(number, message);
}
catch(error){
    console.log(error.name + " occured while sending sms");
}

request.onsuccess = function(){
    console.log("SMS has been sent");
}
request.onerror = function(){
    console.log("Something went wrong: " + this.error);
}
```